# Как назначить событие не DOM улументу

Tags: javascript

я хочу назначить событие сокету:

```
socket = new WebSocket();
socket.addEventListener('myevent', function (event) { });
event = new CustomEvent("myevent");
socket.dispatchEvent(event);
```

получаю ошибку:Cannot read property 'dispatchEvent' of undefined

Comment: У `WebSocket`а отсутствует метод [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#Methods), если вы хотите получить ответ на свой вопрос, то рекомендую его исправить следующим образом: дописать в исходный вопрос, что вы хотите сделать

Comment: допустим я создаю объект:

Comment: class MyClass{}

Comment: object=new MyClass();

Comment: могу я как нибудь в этом объекте сгенерировать событие?

Comment: "могу я как нибудь в этом объекте сгенерировать событие?" - какое?

Answer (score 2):

```js
class MyClass {
  #handlers = {};
  addEventListener(eventName, handler) {
    this.#handlers[eventName] = this.#handlers[eventName] || [];
    this.#handlers[eventName].push(handler);
  }
  triggerEvent(eventName) {
    if (this.#handlers[eventName]) {
      this.#handlers[eventName].forEach(item =>
        item.call(this));
    }
  }
}

var obj = new MyClass();
obj.addEventListener("vacation", () => console.log("We are on vacation"));
obj.triggerEvent("vacation");
```

Comment: Я конечно понимаю, что вам всё здесь кажется удивительно просто и примитивно, чего тут объяснять? :)  Да, для людей, которые читают код с листа, комментарии не нужны, как впрочем и код ответа, так как сами могут его написать. Но ведь спрашивают люди совсем другого уровня, для которых крайне важны  хоть самые краткие пояснения. Конечно не из серии - **"Как-то так"**

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Признаться, я сомневаюсь, что это то, что нужно автору. Начал-то он с `WebSocket`-a, а в комментариях перешел на `MyClass`.

Comment: То есть, не смотря на свои  способности телепата вы не смогли догадаться? :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT И мои компьютерные гномики еще спят.

Comment: Спасибо, это да ответ на вопрос, но я так и не могу понять, как мне сделать следующее:socket.onmessage = function (data) {}

Comment: function (data) {
              
                switch (JSON.parse(data.data).type) {
                    case 'session':
                        onOpen() вызвать событие как??
                                      break;

Comment: то есть в зависимости от того, что пришло в socket.onmessage нужно сгенерировать событие.  socket = new WebSocket() и все его события нужно обернуть в свой класс